# Android calling MyAdapter.bindView many times with position=0 ; how to avoid this?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am working on a class which extends a ListAdapter, and I am unsatisfied with its performance. I'm trying to improve the fluidity of my application, and I have identified this adapter's bindView as a source of lag.

My layout is a grid of items, which are all the same size. I expect bindView() to be called once for each visible item in the grid. Instead, when I trace out the value of Cursor.getPosition(), I see many calls being made for position=0, followed by one call for each visible item in the grid. This is perplexing to me, as well as being apparently wasteful of precious cycles on the UI thread. I speculate that Android is calling bindView(position=0) in order to measure the layout, but I don't actually know what's going on here. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what yet.

What is Android trying to do for me, and how can I modify my code to avoid this behavior? Is there a straightforward way to short-circuit the measure cycle, to tell Android, "hey - I know these items are all going to be the same size - you only need to do one measure pass"?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you are using `GridView`, and you set `layout_height` to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Hm, you know - it's a funny thing. I have a layout which specifies "wrap_content" as layoutHeight, but it's an empty layout. At run time I am inflating a different layout altogether (this is a good choice for us, for reasons which are unimportant to the discussion). In the replacement layout, I'm setting height=match_parent. I guess I'll have to step into there and see which version of the attribute is actually taking at runtime.

Comment: So if you set the `layout_height` of the `GridView` to `wrap_content`, then the framework will call `bindView` several times to measure the height of the `GridView`, which is similar to `ListView`.

Comment: I'll try modifying along the lines you suggest and let you know how it works for me. Thank you!

Comment: It appears I was "over-invalidating" my Adapter, calling notifyDataSetChanged a lot, therefore triggering lots of these calls. I'm not sure whether this had a large impact on performance, but by trimming how eager I was to invalidate the adapter, the incidence of this problem has been substantially reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, if the list/grid is being measured with the `AT_MOST` mode for height (which generally corresponds to `wrap_content`, but this can also happen for other reasons - nested `match_parent`/`wrap_content` configurations, for example) then extra measurement will often be performed.

However, you should strive to keep your `getView`/`bindView` code paths extraordinarily cheap. The system will call into this whenever it feels like it, but during rapid flings this also happens naturally. Cases during layout won't affect you if you're also fast enough in these code paths to handle a usual fling.

Also be careful what you change in your item views asynchronously, such as `setImageDrawable` calls on ImageViews in response to async loading tasks and the like. ListView and GridView have fast paths for anything set during `getView`, but changing things out of band will often trigger a layout. There are ways to keep this fast but you'll need to keep sizes constant to do so.